# How do i save the id of the record on another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two CRUDS in my application:

```
Person : id, name, email
Documents: id, name, number, person_id
```

When i create a new person on the CRUD, I need to automatically set the `person_id` on the Documents table.

I try with a callback `before_save` but I don't know how to pass the params in the right way.

I can do directly on the `PersonController`?

How I can do this?

I think I'm not clear in my question.

```
People has_many :documents
Documents belongs_to :people
```

The documents will not be inserted by the user. The documents will be inserted by one rake task that will take the documents from an external source.

When the rake task try to insert a new document, the document search the person_id on the documents table. If the `person_id` is not present, the document is not saved. This is my main problem.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. When you create a person, are you also creating a document?

Comment: You need to automatically set the person_id on *all rows* of the Documents table?

Comment: I thing im not clear in my question.

People has many documents
Documents belongs_to people.

The documents will not be inserted by the user. The documents will be inserted by one rake task that will take the documents from a external source.

When the rake task try to insert a new document, the document search the person_id on the documents table. If the person_id is not present, the document is not saved. This is my main problem.

Comment: You'll need to set up some associations. Read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: The associations has present. See the edit on question

Comment: Where do you choose the person_id? Could you show the rake task?

Comment: @FábioJansen Why don't you post the controller action where you create a Person, **and** the rake task as well. That way we can see how it actually works, and can advise you from there. Its still unclear how your situation works from the description so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet so I'm putting this in an answer. If I understand you correctly, when you create a person you want to automatically create an associated document?
If that's the case then you could try adding the following in your persons model.

```
after_save :create_document

def create_document
    @document = Document.create(
        :person_id => self.id,
        # any other needed code
    )
end
```

I used after_save because this way you are calling on an object that is already created instead of trying to pass a person_id to documents before that person is created. This solution probably isn't the most elegant one around but it might help for the time being until someone can reply with something better.

Comment: Im using this form and is working as expected. If dont have any other way, i will continue using this method

Comment: Glad it works, I just realised that this will create a new document even when a person is modified or updated so you might want to add some validation to make sure that the document record does not already exist before calling .create()